# How did Tank die?

Tags: the-matrix

It is suggested in Matrix-Reloaded that Tank has died.  A conversation between Zee and Link seem to imply that Tank is a goner but he seemed to have been more or less OK by the end of The Matrix (although with a pretty heavy wound).

So, how did he die?

Comment: The story of the actor is interesting: http://www.theguardian.com/film/2003/may/20/news

Comment: Wow... That is very interesting indeed.  Thanks for sharing that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the Matrix wiki, [Tank](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Tank) dies of [unspecified causes](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Tank#Death).

> Death
>
> It is unclear if Tank's death was the result of the severe
> wound he sustained from the energy bolt, or of unrelated causes.
> Regardless, he is deceased by the time of The Matrix Reloaded, with
> his place as operator filled by his brother-in-law, Link, who is
> married to Tank's sister Zee.